# How to use DIY keyboard connected to spi (gpio) of single board computer

Tags: sensors, hardware, linux

I want to build a diy keyboard which connect to the spi interface of the gpio header of the orange pi 5 (ubuntu/linux).
So far I have some sketches of the keyboard, the schematic is in progress.

The controller of the keyboard will be a microcontroller with spi embedded, it will deliver scancodes to the host.
My goal is it to use my diy as standard keyboard under ubuntu.
I am a Linux beginner, so my struggle right now is the software of the host computer. Do I have to write my own keyboard driver ? Where to start ?

Any help like pointing out readings or sample code in c is welcome.

Comment: which part of your post is about IoT?

Comment: what is the host device? ... how are the scan codes sent to the host?

Comment: i chosed to put my question into the IoT category because of the host device(sorry for not mentioning it in the first place). it will be a single board computer with a rockchip rk3588 SoC running linux(debian). the sbc has a gpio header with spi connectivity. meanwhile i found a way to use the spi of the sbc with the libmraa GPIO library for c. so i can write code to xchange data with the microcontroller of the keyboard. but i want the data obtained from my keyboard to be used as key press info for the standard keyboard. i have no clue how the keyboard is implemented into the linux system.

Comment: that does not make it an IoT question ... if you were building a camping trailer, and had a question about attaching the roof to the walls, would you go to a Ford website, because you plan to pull the trailer with a Ford truck?

Comment: please add all the details about the keyboard and the SBC to the question ... this site is not a forum ... information does not belong in comments

Comment: yep, not really IOT as is probably more embedded systems but there's no such category around here that fit the purpose.
There's two approach to what you want to do: userspace or kernel. If you go for the userspace approach look here I guess it can get you started : https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/reading-and-writing-to-the-linux-keyboard-buffer-4175416506/, if you want to do it kernelspace you can look for the input subsystem.